# Proving two determinants are equal

Tags: determinant

Using determinant properties (without expanding), prove that

$$ \begin{vmatrix}yz & z^2 & y^2 \\ z^2 & xz & x^2 \\ y^2 & x^2 & xy \end{vmatrix} =  
xyz\begin{vmatrix}x & z & y \\ z & y & x \\ y & x &z\end{vmatrix}$$

I'm completely lost and I don't know what to try. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to find the determinant of a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: I only know how to calculate the value of a 3x3 determinant.

Comment: then calculate the determinate of you 3by3 matrices?

Comment: Then just calculate both determinants and simplify both sides.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you're not allowed to expand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start from

$$\begin{vmatrix}x & z & y \\ z & y & x \\ y & x &z\end{vmatrix}.$$

Multiply the colums by $y, x, \frac{xy}z$; multiply the rows by $\frac{z}{x},\frac z y, 1$. You have now multiplied the determinant with $xyz$.

Edit: More symmetric: multiply the colums $yz, zx, xy$; multiply the rows by $\frac1x,\frac1y, \frac1z$.

Comment: Ingenious. Any tip on how you discovered that this sequence of operations would work?

Comment: This uses that $x,y,z$ must each be invertible, which is against the spirit of determinants. More precisely makes the proof invalid over general commutative rings. And in any case it obliges you to do some special cases.

Comment: @Henning If you guess $y$ and $z/x$ then there is at most one possibility for the other options. There is further freedom because you can multiply all rows by the same number and divide all colums by the same number so there is really only one degree of freedom.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Actually the above argument proves it for the 'universal' ring $\Bbb Z[x,y,z]$ by considering its fraction field where $x,y,z$ are invertible and then, because the it is just a polynomial, it holds in any ring $R$ for any variables $a,b,c$ by using the evaluation morphism $\Bbb Z[x,y,z] \mapsto R: f(x,y,z)\mapsto \bar f(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @Myself: Yes I know. But (just to be obnoxious) how do you prove the determinant is a polynomial in the matrix entries without using expansion?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I guess that depends on how you wish to define the determinant... Some people define it as a polynomial (and then you must prove the multilinear properties). Others as the unique multilinear map with some properties, or the induced map ${\wedge^n} V\to {\wedge^n} V : x\mapsto \mathrm{det}(\alpha)x$ etc. But inevitably at some point someone, like an author of a text on linear algebra, has to do a bit of work to tie everything together :-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Sarrus' scheme gives it immediately.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus